# PHP / SQLSRV / json_encode. Help required for JSON encoding a record array

Tags: php, json, sqlsrv

I am retrieving data from a SQL Server Database using the following code:

```
$sql = "EXEC usp_APIGetJob @Reference='BAX94319',@OrderRef='ORD00156',@JobRef='012363';";
$RS_Result01 = sqlsrv_query($conn,$sql);
$result = array();
do {
    while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($RS_Result01,SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $result[] = $row;
    }
}
while (sqlsrv_next_result($RS_Result01));

print_r($result);
```

The print_r outputs the following array:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [SiteId] => 4894 [ClientId] => 2334 [OrderRef] => ORD00156 [JobRef] => 012363 [MovementRef] => 200781 [WeighBridgeRef] => 200801 [WeighBridgeWeight] => 4.560 [PercentFill] => 100 [BreakdownPercentage] => 25 [BreakdownDescription] => Cardboard (packaging) [BreakdownEWC] => 15-01-01 ) )
```

You can see from the array that this array structure is capable of showing multiple rows. In the interests of simplicity I have only returned one row ([0]) for this question.

I would like to format this output to JSON using a json_encode() but I am struggling to find the correct statement/syntax to create the JSON format.

Every time I attempt to echo the json_encode() it produces nothing (blank output).

Any help with correctly formatting a json_encode() to encode this array, along with a brief overview of the thinking behind it (so I can learn) would be greatly appreciated.

The version of SQL Server is 2012 so using the new JSON OUTPUT functionality of SQL Server 2016/2017 is not an option. I have to encode in PHP.

Kind regards

Comment: What is result of `var_dump(json_encode($result))` ?

Comment: added var_dump(json_encode($result)) and all I got was: bool(false)

Comment: Try to use `json_last_error` to see the error message in the case that json_encode fails

Comment: It returned a '5'. Just looking at the manual to see what that means.

Comment: Looks like JSON_ERROR_UTF8 - Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded.

Comment: Check your SQL Server character encodig, maybe it's not utf8

Comment: I'm looking at utf8_encode($result) but that falls over expecting a string not an array. There has to be a better way of utf8_encoding. Perhaps on the retrieve?

Comment: I just checked the Database - good old 'SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS'

Comment: In my case SQL Server had windows-1250 encoding and simplest way to convert was iconv function for every field in an array

Answer (score 1):

With A LOT of pointers from Bart the answer was that the json_encode required UTF-8 encoding to work. The simple answer to this was to include a 'CharacterSet' modification to the connection string.

```
$connectionInfo = array( "UID"=>$uid,"PWD"=>$pwd,"Database"=>$database,"CharacterSet"=> "UTF-8");
```

It makes the output UTF-8 and allows the json_encode() to run like a beauty!

Once again, Thank you Bart for pointing me in the right debug direction and all your help. I hope this solution is useful to you in the future as well.

I feel you deserve the credit for this.

:)